# Opening a .txt file in python for name generator

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, decode, python-unicode

I am very new to python and just started to code some mini projects. Currently I am trying to create a code that picks a random first name from a .txt file and combines it with a random last name from a seperate .txt file. This is my code so far:

```
import random

firstname = "/Desktop/Python/Namelists/firstnames.txt"
firstnames = open(firstname, "rb").read().splitlines()

lastname = "/Desktop/Python/Namelists/firstnames.txt"
lastnames = open(lastname, "rb").read().splitlines()

name1 = random.sample(firstnames, 1)
name2 = random.sample(lastnames, 1)

name = name1 + name2

print(name)
```

I first tried to open the files without using "rb", but that gave me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 1: invalid start byte
```

So I told python to read the files as binary. This works, but it gives me the output as a byte-string:

```
[b'Adam', b'Weber']
```

I want the output to be in plain text, every try to decode failed.

I am running Python 3.9.7 on MacOS Monterey. The .txt files are encoded in us-ascii.

**EDIT: I use german names and so there are some special-characters such as "Ü, Ö and Ä".**

Comment: You have to open the files with the correct encoding. It isn’t UTF8 and it isn’t ASCII which doesn’t support German umlauts. Ideally, re-save the files in UTF8 which supports any Unicode code point.  Then use `open(file, encoding='utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file in binary mode "rb". Try:

```
lastnames = open(lastname, "r").read().splitlines()
```

Comment: I tried it already. This gives me the UnicodeDecodeError mentioned above :(

Comment: try adding a encoding header on top of the file:  # encoding: utf-8

Comment: alternatively you can try: utf8_file = open("sample.txt", encoding="UTF-8")

Comment: Doesn't work. BTW I edited my post, because I forgot to mention that I use special characters like 'ü, ö and ä' in the .txt file. I think this is where the problem comes from.

Comment: I now removed all special characters from my .txt file and changed the "rb" to "r" and it works, but it still gives me the output as a binary string.

Comment: @user9468014 `# encoding: utf-8` only declares the encoding of the source file and has nothing to do with the encoding `open` uses.

Answer (score 0):

Code below is working but I think you set lastnames to "/Desktop/Python/Namelists/firstnames.txt" by mistake. If it's not, you can edit that in code.

```
import random

firstnames_file = open("/Desktop/Python/Namelists/firstnames.txt", "r")  # The file opened
firstnames = firstnames_file.read().split()  # It read file (type: list)

lastnames_file = open("/Desktop/Python/Namelists/lastnames.txt", "r")  # The file opened
lastnames = lastnames_file.read().split()  # It read file (type: list)

firstname = random.choice(firstnames)  # choosen a random value in the list
lastname = random.choice(lastnames)  # choosen a random value in the list

print(f"Name:{firstname}, Surname:{lastname}")
```

Note: Code works if in the txt file, every name has spaces between each other, like "Ben Emma Leon Mia" or "Ben (enter) Emma (enter) Leon (enter) Mia" (Sorry stack overflow don't allows adding line)